# subtotals by group R

Tags: r, subtotal

I'm trying to find a function similar to SAS's Proc Means which will aggregate data and subtotal/total it by groups.

For example I have:

```
Var1    Var2
 a       b  
 a       c  
 b       b
```

and I want to create:

```
Var1    Var2    N
 a       b      1
 a       c      1
 b       b      1
 na      b      2
 na      c      1
 a       na     2
 b       na     1
 na      na     3
```

I've found that Summarise() and Aggregate() are able to do this but without the subtotals. 
There is also a Cube() function in development for data.table which does this, but I can only download from CRAN due to our IT security policy.

As you can probably tell, I'm new to R so I'm sorry if this is a fairly simple question.

Thanks!

Comment: But data.table is on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `DF` in the Note at the end try this one-liner.  The same code works if there are a different number of columns.  Also try it without the `as.data.frame` for wide format.  No packages are used.

```
as.data.frame(addmargins(xtabs(~., DF)))
```

giving:

```
  Var1 Var2 Freq
1    a    b    1
2    b    b    1
3  Sum    b    2
4    a    c    1
5    b    c    0
6  Sum    c    1
7    a  Sum    2
8    b  Sum    1
9  Sum  Sum    3
```

### Note

`DF` in reproducible form is:

```
DF <- structure(list(Var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("a", 
"b"), class = "factor"), Var2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("b", 
"c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way you could do this, using [`bind_rows`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html) and [`count`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tally.html) from [**`dplyr`**](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/).

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% count(Var1, Var2) %>% # count by Var1 and Var2
    bind_rows(dat %>% count(Var1)) %>% # count by Var1
    bind_rows(dat %>% count(Var2)) %>% # count by Var2
    bind_rows(dat %>% count) # count rows

  Var1  Var2      n
  <chr> <chr> <int>
1 a     b         1
2 a     c         1
3 b     b         1
4 a     NA        2
5 b     NA        1
6 NA    b         2
7 NA    c         1
8 NA    NA        3
```

#### data

```
dat <- read.table(text = "Var1    Var2
 a       b  
 a       c  
 b       b", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE)
```